# Getting wrong data with NSURLRequest when using multiple url's

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsurlconnection, grand-central-dispatch

In my project i am using 2 api's in same class. and i want to get data using NSURLRequest,in first api i am getting latitude longitude of places and put these latitude longitude on second url for getting distance between these places but i am getting same distance with each places

here is my code.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
    currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil){

        NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=%f,%f&radius=2000&types=%@&sensor=false&key=API Key",currentLocation.coordinate.latitude,currentLocation.coordinate.longitude,strCatText];
        [self createTheConnection:str];
        //[self createTheConnection1:str1];

        arrAllData=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        int i;
        for (i=0; i<=2; i++)
        {
            NSString *strname=[[[arr valueForKey:@"results"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"name"];
            NSString *strvicinity=[[[arr valueForKey:@"results"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"vicinity"];
            NSString *strRef=[[[arr valueForKey:@"results"]objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"reference"];
            NSString *strLat=[[[[[arr valueForKey:@"results"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"geometry"] valueForKey:@"location"] valueForKey:@"lat"];
            NSString *strLng=[[[[[arr valueForKey:@"results"] objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"geometry"] valueForKey:@"location"] valueForKey:@"lng"];

            int j;
            for (j=0; j<=0; j++)
            {
               NSString *str1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%f,%f&destination=%@,%@&sensor=false&mode=driving",currentLocation.coordinate.latitude,currentLocation.coordinate.longitude,strLat,strLng];
                //NSLog(@"%@",str1);
                [self createTheConnection1:str1];

              //  if (![strLat isEqual:@"0"]) {
               //   strDistance=@"";
                  NSString *strDistance=[[[[[[arr2 valueForKey:@"routes"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"legs"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"distance"] valueForKey:@"text"];
               // NSLog(@"%@",strDistance);
                //}

                if(strname == nil){
                    strname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [NSNull null]];
                }
                if(strvicinity == nil){
                    strvicinity = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [NSNull null]];
                }
                if(strRef == nil){
                    strRef = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [NSNull null]];
                }
                if(strDistance == nil){
                    strDistance = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [NSNull null]];
                }

                if (![strDistance isEqual:@"<null>"]) {
                    arrdata=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:strname,strvicinity,strRef,strDistance, nil];
                    strDistance=nil;

                    [arrAllData addObject:arrdata];
                }       

            }          
           [tblView reloadData];  
        } 
    }



-(void)createTheConnection:(NSString*)strUrl
{    
    NSMutableURLRequest *request=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[strUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];

    connections=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if(connections)
    {
        webData=[NSMutableData data];

    }

}

-(void)createTheConnection1:(NSString*)strUrl1
{

    NSMutableURLRequest *request1=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[strUrl1 stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];

    connections1=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request1 delegate:self];

    if(connections1)
    {
        webData1=[NSMutableData data];

    }

}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

    //  //NSLog(@"%@",error);

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=nil;

}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
    if (connection==connections) {
        [webData appendData:data];
    }
    if (connection==connections1) {
        [webData1 appendData:data];
    }


}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
    if (connection==connections) {
        [webData setLength:0];
    }
    if (connection==connections1) {
        [webData1 setLength:0];
    }


}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{   

    NSError *err;   
    if (connection==connections) {
        arr=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];
    }
    if (connection==connections1) {
        arr2=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData1 options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];      
    }  
}


-(void)barBtnItem1{
    MapViewController *mvc =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mapview"];
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"Start" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.80];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mvc animated:YES];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return arrAllData.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    UILabel *lblName=(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    UILabel *lblAddress=(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    UILabel *lblDistance=(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:102];
    arrData11=[arrAllData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *strName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",arrData11[0]];
    NSString *strAddress=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",arrData11[1]];
    NSString *strDistance1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",arrData11[3]];
    if ([strName isEqual:@"<null>"]) {
//        lblName.text=@"Loading...";
//        lblAddress.text=@"Loading...";
    }
    else{
        lblName.text=strName;
        lblAddress.text=strAddress;
        lblDistance.text=strDistance1;
    }
        return cell;
}
```

Comment: all code is available @suhit

Answer (score 0):

You are creating two connection back to back, when they receive data they are calling the delegates but in you app you didn't wait to get the data from first  request and then make the second request. I am pretty sure the distance you are getting is the distance of second lat and long.

Make single request for these data and see which distance you are getting. And try to make request one by one. i.e make first request.. get the data .. then make second request. Because they are using same delegate to initialize the data.

**EDIT**
I am in mobile so I can not help with you code. I'll give a try..

```
Method A (take parameter that you need to make a url request) {
    //Make request with pair of lat and long and necessary datas
}

(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{   
    ........
    //After getting the data

    Call method A with next pair of lat long 
    You can determine next pair by maintaining a global variable.
}
```

Let me know it that helps...:)

Comment: how can i handle this ,i am very new with GCD..tell me PLZ

Comment: yes i have solved my problem but not in this way....i used CLLocation for getting distance. @Rashad